# Одинаковые и различные поля в базе данных

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Всем привет! Если кто-то сталкивался с подобной задачей, подскажите, пожалуйста, как её реализовать. Есть таблица clients. [Есть форма](http://take.ms/nrfGW), через которую создаётся клиент. Как видно на скрине, в форме можно выбрать физ. лицо или [юр. лицо](http://take.ms/aAJfg). Отличаются они дополнительными полями (в физ. есть паспорт и нет реквизитов, в юр. наоборот). Другими словами: у них есть одинаковые поля и есть различные.

Как обычно реализуют подобного рода задачи? Все поля в одной таблице и используют их по надобности, или есть какой-то более правильный способ?

Comment: 1) Разреженная таблица; 2) Общая таблица плюс частные таблицы; 3) EAV; 4) Сериализация (XML, JSON и т.п.)

Comment: Все поля в одну таблицу и не парьтесь

Comment: @Akina Спасибо за ответ, по первым двум пунктам ничего не смог найти, а EAV, кажется, подходит, только не понятно как задавать типы полей динамически.

Comment: @DaemonHK С ростом проекта сложно будет контролировать :)

Comment: *по первым двум пунктам ничего не смог найти* Разреженная (sparse) таблица - та, в которой много полей заведомо будут NULL. В некоторых СУБД для них имеется специфическая поддержка (увы, не в MySQL). Общая + частная - в общей поля, имеющиеся во всех типах записи, в частных - специфические для какого-то одного типа (каждому типу своя частная таблица). *не понятно как задавать типы полей динамически* Никак - используется наиболее общий тип (строковый или бинарный) либо сериализованный (в случае MySQL это JSON).

Comment: @ДмитрийЮзенков, эм... серьезно?)) Все так радеют и уповают на "развитие проекта", но 90% сайтов это просто визитки/корпоративные/магазины с 1000 товаров и 20 покупками в месяц, которые так никуда и не развиваются. "Преждевременная оптимизация - зло" (с) Кнут